# Event Notification Service Webhook vs. API limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, limits

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createCallback.htm

--> As far as I understood, the Notification Service triggers POST requests to the configured Webhook, once an action I have subscribed to occurs.

Question is: Do the calls send by the Event Notification Service count 
against our contractual API limit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reporting on API limits within the marketing cloud. For incoming calls if your API process is causing an issue they will be [ratelimited](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rate-limiting-errors.htm)